# Trigger.IO video API to play local file

Tags: video-streaming, trigger.io

Can we store video in the local device (iPhone or Android) and play back the video using `media.videoPlay(url, success, error)`, where the URL points to the local directory? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?  (I am currently on a computer **without** forge).

```
forge.file.getLocal('videos/whatever.mpg', function(localFile) {
 forge.media.videoPlay(localFile, function() {}, function(content) {});
}, function(content) {});
```

Comment: getLocal did return a uri with "file://" in front. so I used getURL instead and it is working.  

var url;
forge.tools.getURL("video/infiniti_olive.mp4", function (myUrl) {
    url = myUrl;
    forge.media.videoPlay(myUrl);
});